# How to query the nested JSON structure in MongoDB/Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

The following is one of the document in the MongoDB database.

I want to select the **year**  between 2007 ,2008.

and the key includes **"Actual"** or **"Upper End of Range"**

and the table_name equals to **Unemployment rate**

How to finish it in Mongoid or MongoDB query.

Or I only can do it in application layer like Ruby or Python ?

## id 2012-04-25_unemployment_rate

```
{
  "_id": "2012-04-25_unemployment_rate",
  "table_name": "Unemployment rate",
  "unit": "Percent",
  "data": [
    {
      "2007": [
        {
          "Actual": "3.5"
        },
        {
          "Upper End of Range": "-"
        },
        {
          "Upper End of Central Tendency": "-"
        },
        {
          "Lower End of Central Tendency": "-"
        },
        {
          "Lower End of Range": "-"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "2008": [
        {
          "Actual": "1.7"
        },
        {
          "Upper End of Range": "-"
        },
        {
          "Upper End of Central Tendency": "-"
        },
        {
          "Lower End of Central Tendency": "-"
        },
        {
          "Lower End of Range": "-"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

## id 2014-04-25_unemployment_rate

```
{
  "_id": "2014-04-25_unemployment_rate",
  "table_name": "Unemployment rate",
  "unit": "Percent",
  "data": [
    {
      "2008": [
        {
          "Actual": "3.5"
        },
        {
          "Upper End of Range": "-"
        },
        {
          "Upper End of Central Tendency": "-"
        },
        {
          "Lower End of Central Tendency": "-"
        },
        {
          "Lower End of Range": "-"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "2009": [
        {
          "Actual": "1.7"
        },
        {
          "Upper End of Range": "-"
        },
        {
          "Upper End of Central Tendency": "-"
        },
        {
          "Lower End of Central Tendency": "-"
        },
        {
          "Lower End of Range": "-"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't select documents by keys; you select documents by values. You should restructure your documents to have fields like `"year" : 2007`. For example,

```
{
    "_id": "2012-04-25_unemployment_rate",
    "table_name": "Unemployment rate",
    "unit": "Percent",
    "data": [
        {
            "year" : 2007,
            "Actual": "3.5",
            "Upper End of Range": "-",
            "Upper End of Central Tendency": "-",
            "Lower End of Central Tendency": "-",
            "Lower End of Range": "-"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by the condition that "key includes 'Actual' or 'Upper End of Range'", but if you want documents with a data element with `year` 2007 or 2008 and `table_name` equal to `"Unemployment rate"`, use the query spec

```
{ "table_name" : "Unemployment rate", "data.year" : { "$in" : [2007, 2008] } }
```